# Reducing stock quantity in MySQL database after doing a sale in Java

Tags: java, mysql

The following code is my method to update database with new remaining stock quantity after a sale.

In my form the **tablesale** has dynamic rows. Means that user can add 1 or more as he like.

So I used for loop for get current table row and get relevant ItemID from the tablesale and search it in db and finally reducing the sold qty and the result is updated to the database.

My code;

```
//redusing stock in db

            for(int rcount=0;rcount<=tableSale.getRowCount();rcount++){

            rcount = tableSale.getRowCount();

            String idsale = (String) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(rcount, 0);

            String sql0= "select * from druginfo where ItemID=?";

            pst0=conn.prepareStatement(sql0);
            pst0.setString(1, idsale);

            rs0= pst0.executeQuery();

            if(rs0.next()){
                String instock = rs0.getString("InStock");

                int nowstock=Integer.parseInt(instock);
                int soldqty = (int) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(rcount, 3);

                int newstock = nowstock - soldqty;

                System.out.println("new :"+newstock);

                String sqlupdate= "update druginfo set InStock='"+newstock+"' where ItemID='"+idsale+"'";
                pst=conn.prepareStatement(sqlupdate);
                pst.execute();
                System.out.println("Done");

            }
         }
```

But Codes throws an Exception as below;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.saveprint_btnActionPerformed(Newsale.java:1009)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.access$1300(Newsale.java:57)
at com.bit.project.Newsale$16.actionPerformed(Newsale.java:651)
```

line 1009 is `String idsale = (String) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(rcount, 0);`. Help me to fix this error.

[image]

Comment: What is the `tableSale` belongs List or something else?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077880/5193194) answer

Comment: Your exception clearly said you are trying to access those element which not present in the table..Please let me know the total row/columns in your if i am not wrong in `JTable`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I added a screenshot. As you see User can add many rows as preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

---

```
for(int rcount=0;rcount<=tableSale.getRowCount();rcount++){
```

---

with this

---

```
for(int rcount=0;rcount<tableSale.getRowCount();rcount++){
```

As indexes are count from 0 and, if row count is 1 max index will be 0. It will crash on index 1 this will fix the issue.

---

ok, above issue is valid and another thing is

rcount = tableSale.getRowCount();

rcount is your loop variable. Why are you assigning it table row count. Row count is always max index+1 t will always cause index out of bound. Remove this line and then check.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int rcount=0;rcount<tblProduct.getRowCount();rcount++){
        String idsale = (String) tblProduct.getModel().getValueAt(rcount, 0);

        String sql0= "select * from productsinformation where ProductID=?";

        stm=conn.prepareStatement(sql0);
        stm.setString(1, idsale);

        ResultSet rs= stm.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            String instock = rs.getString("Stock");
            int nowstock=Integer.parseInt(instock);
            int newstock = nowstock - 1;
            String sqlupdate= "update productsinformation set Stock='"+newstock+"' where ProductID='"+idsale+"'";
            stm=conn.prepareStatement(sqlupdate);
            stm.execute();


        }
    }
```

Comment: please provide a short description to your solution so everybody will know why you chosen it